# BigQuery: Questions on Delete and Update rows using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I've found a lot of `node.js` examples to query and insert data into BigQuery but didn't find any example nor API description on how to delete and update rows in the database. I am aware of the limitations (30 minutes since last change, etc.).

The only tip I've found I got from `vscode`

```
bigQuery.dataset(dataset).table(table).deleteFromBigQuery('noIdea')
```

But even vscode couldn't give me a tip about updating.

Do you know any `nodejs` documentation on this?

Some of resources I've been looking for 
[query examples by googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/queries.js) and
[DMLs google Manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language)

Comment: Are you trying to delete rows in a table, or to delete the table itself? You probably want to execute either a DELETE or a DROP query.

Comment: can you post any of the examples you've found on how to run a query? we can probably modify it then to one that runs an update

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, here is a query example https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/queries.js

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, I need to delete rows from a query, not the table itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building on the [`sync_query` example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/query.js):

```
async function runDeleteQuery(projectId) {
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
   */
  // const projectId = "your-project-id";

  // Modify this query however you need
  const sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM dataset.table WHERE condition;";

  // Creates a client
  const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId});

  // Query options list: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query
  const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    timeoutMs: 100000, // Time out after 100 seconds.
    useLegacySql: false, // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
  };

  // Runs the query
  await bigquery.query(options);
}
```

See also the [DELETE statement documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement).

Comment: So, to update a table I use the same approach, execute a query. Thanks